# Azure script task when failOnStderr: true , bash error arise which wasn't without this flag

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

i have wired behavior
when the failOnStderr: true is not set in the task everything working fine BUT
when i invoke the script task like this with failOnStderr: true:

```
- script:  |
     echo 'Start invoking Fastfile'
     fastlane release --verbose projectName:${{parameters.projectName}} appIdentifier:${{parameters.appIdentifier}} versionNumber:${{parameters.versionNumber}} buildNumber:${{parameters.buildNumber}} plistFileFtpBasePath:${{parameters.plistFileFtpBasePath}} ArtifactsDirectory:$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
     echo 'Done invoking Fastfile'
    failOnStderr: true 
    workingDirectory: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/ios_artifacts'
    displayName: 'create keychain invoke fastlane'
```

I'm getting this errors :

```
2020-09-30T07:54:45.8179430Z INFO [2020-09-30 07:54:45.81]: [32mfastlane.tools finished successfully ðŸŽ‰[0m
2020-09-30T07:54:45.8917310Z Done invoking Fastfile
2020-09-30T07:54:45.8948720Z 
2020-09-30T07:54:45.9020160Z ##[error]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
2020-09-30T07:54:45.9033610Z ##[error]/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.1/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.161.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:141: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.1/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.161.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/errors/fastlane_error.rb:9: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9035550Z ##[error]security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9037370Z ##[error]/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.1/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.161.0/gym/lib/gym/generators/package_command_generator_xcode7.rb:154: warning: URI.escape is obsolete

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9040080Z ##[error]/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.1/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.161.0/gym/lib/gym/generators/package_command_generator_xcode7.rb:155: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.1/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.161.0/gym/lib/gym/generators/package_command_generator_xcode7.rb:156: warning: URI.escape is obsolete

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9042740Z ##[error]warning: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-30/xxxx_2019.1.4.xxxx-xxxx.1.1.0.4_SPRINT_14 2020-09-30 07.51.27.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/1BD5CB31-31FC-328B-A827-73EA51BB6041.bcsymbolmap: No such file or directory: not unobfuscating.

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9045210Z ##[error]warning: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-30/xxxx_1.1.xxxx-xxxx.1.1.0.4_SPRINT_14 2020-09-30 07.51.27.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/9FCBA8ED-D8FD-3C16-9740-5E2A31F3E959.bcsymbolmap: No such file or directory: not unobfuscating.

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9047670Z ##[error]warning: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-30/xxxx_1.1.xxxx-xxxx.1.1.0.4_SPRINT_14 2020-09-30 07.51.27.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/999C2967-8A06-3CD5-82D7-D156E9440A0C.bcsymbolmap: No such file or directory: not unobfuscating.

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9050110Z ##[error]warning: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-30/xxxx_1.1.xxxx-xxxx.1.1.0.4_SPRINT_14 2020-09-30 07.51.27.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/EB7DF7BE-351D-3A4A-949C-0AE12606A3E2.bcsymbolmap: No such file or directory: not unobfuscating.

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9052570Z ##[error]warning: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-30/xxxx_1.1.xxxx-xxxx.1.1.0.4_SPRINT_14 2020-09-30 07.51.27.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/9702769F-1F06-3001-AB75-5AD38E1F7D66.bcsymbolmap: No such file or directory: not unobfuscating.

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9055030Z ##[error]warning: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-30/xxxx_1.1.xxxx-xxxx.1.1.0.4_SPRINT_14 2020-09-30 07.51.27.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/D560471D-F43F-30D6-9717-5252EE100F10.bcsymbolmap: No such file or directory: not unobfuscating.

2020-09-30T07:54:45.9056620Z ##[error]Additional writes to stderr truncated
2020-09-30T07:54:45.9063410Z ##[section]Finishing: create keychain invoke fastlane
```

**UPDATE**
when setting to false still not working

```
- script:  |
     echo 'Start invoking Fastfile'
     fastlane release --verbose projectName:${{parameters.projectName}} appIdentifier:${{parameters.appIdentifier}} versionNumber:${{parameters.versionNumber}} buildNumber:${{parameters.buildNumber}} plistFileFtpBasePath:${{parameters.plistFileFtpBasePath}} ArtifactsDirectory:$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
     echo 'Done invoking Fastfile'
    failOnStderr: false
    workingDirectory: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/ios_artifacts'
    displayName: 'create keychain invoke fastlane'
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is an expected behavior.

Once you set `failOnStderr: true`, then task will fail if **any errors are written** to the **StandardError** stream.

[image]

Conversely, if `failOnStderr` is `false`, the failure of task will depends on the **exit code**. Task will fail while **exit code** is not **0**.

As normal, you should have known that errors are written into **stderr** will not result in the **exit code** will be non-zero. The `failOnStderr` is `true` or `false` are two different failure conditions.

According to the log you shared:

```
2020-09-30T07:54:45.9020160Z ##[error]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
```

You can see there are some errors write into **Stderr** stream. At this moment, task failed as expected since you set `failOnStderr` to `true`.

**Updated**:

Sample:

Succeed with warning:

[image]

Failed with stderr:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your informative response, this all good and understood but what i meant is 
that when i set this property suddenly i have those errors to the stderr .
without this property, everything is working fine and i DO not see the bash stderr in logs

Comment: @user63898, if you do not set failOnStderr, as normal, those messages will display as **warning**. See my updated sample.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so to how can i fail this task when "REAL" application errors are rising? failOnStderr =false ?

Comment: @user63898. yep! The real application errors should lead your process exit with non-zero. If you set failOnStderr =false for tasks, then tasks' failure will depend on tasks' **exit code**.

Comment: Thanks, @Merlin Liang - MSFT   can you please look into this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151412/azure-hosted-mac-pipeline-suggestion-on-how-to-make-it-faster-currently-very

Comment: it didn't work when set to failOnStderr: false
i got an error to the stdErr and the script task still successfully pass 
see image attached in the original question

Comment: @user63898, I'm sure that if you reproduce this issue on your local machine, you would encounter same circumstance. Because you are calling fastlane in command line task, and fastlane do not think the "no profile" error is a fatal issue of the process. Then it continued the next sub-process until fastlane encounter an fatal error and terminate the execution of the process.

Comment: its working just fine with fastlane , it compiles to iOS app 
which is working great . 
only when i set the Flag true or false the build got broken ... 
with not working , without working ....
another idea can i configure the next task task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
to fail if no compilation products are found ?

Comment: @user63898 I got that. Refer to this code snippet of cmd task: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/CmdLineV2/cmdline.ts#L51. FailOnStderr flag will not be the cause of the error you faced. What I means is if you reproduce the same error on your local, you will see the execution process does not terminate by this error.(I know everything working fine on local, just discussing the scenario that why task is green with error ) Finally, we still need fix no profile issue.

Comment: @user63898 For your second idea, where is this downloadbuildartifact task located? The first task of the next job?

Comment: check this question you will see my pipeline, by the way, thanks for your help